# JNA call SetTcpEntry always returning 317

Tags: java, windows, tcp, jna, uac

I am currently writing a testing/simulation software that shall imitate a certain behavior of a communication client using a proprietary TCP/IP protocol. To simulate a broken connection I want to just kick an open client socket out of the list. After some research I found that the SetTcpEntry method from the [iphlpapi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-settcpentry) is a candidate to do this.
I have successfully implemented this approach in Java using JNA. But even if I run my simulation software as administrator the SetTcpEntry call returns 317. From its documentation I found that this indicates that the program is running non-elevated. But reading from some other [doc](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/319748-process-see-if-running-administrator-elevated.html) which explains how to check manually for UAC elevation, I know that the program IS running elevated.
Has anyone had similar problems with this kind of call? And how could I solve this problem? Maybe there is some other way to get rid of my socket.

For completness, thi sis the Java code to delete a socket:

```
    public static boolean killSocket(final IoSession p_ioSession)
    {
        LogMF.info(LOGGER, "Attemtping to delete TCP connection {0} - {1}", p_ioSession.getLocalAddress(), p_ioSession.getRemoteAddress());

        final MIB_TCPROW.ByReference entry = new MIB_TCPROW.ByReference();
        entry.dwLocalAddr.setValue(CodecUtil.getInt(CodecUtil.skipOrder(((InetSocketAddress) p_ioSession.getLocalAddress()).getAddress().getAddress())));
        entry.dwLocalPort.setValue(htons(((InetSocketAddress) p_ioSession.getLocalAddress()).getPort()));
        entry.dwRemoteAddr.setValue(CodecUtil.getInt(CodecUtil.skipOrder(((InetSocketAddress) p_ioSession.getRemoteAddress()).getAddress().getAddress())));
        entry.dwRemotePort.setValue(htons(((InetSocketAddress) p_ioSession.getRemoteAddress()).getPort()));
        entry.state.State = MIB_TCP_STATE_DELETE_TCB;
        entry.state.setType("State");

        final int ret = library.SetTcpEntry(entry).intValue();

        if (ret == 0)
        {
            LogMF.info(LOGGER, "TCP connection {0} - {1} marked deleted", p_ioSession.getLocalAddress(), p_ioSession.getRemoteAddress());
            return true;
        }

        switch (ret)
        {
            case ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED:
                LogMF.error(LOGGER, "Failed to delete TCP connection {0} - {1}: Access is denied. Run as administrator.",
                        new Object[] { p_ioSession.getLocalAddress(), p_ioSession.getRemoteAddress() });
                break;
            case ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                LogMF.error(LOGGER, "Failed to delete TCP connection {0} - {1}: IPv4 is not configured.", new Object[] { p_ioSession.getLocalAddress(), p_ioSession.getRemoteAddress() });
                break;
            case ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER:
                LogMF.error(LOGGER, "Failed to delete TCP connection {0} - {1}: Invaid function argument", new Object[] { p_ioSession.getLocalAddress(), p_ioSession.getRemoteAddress() });
                break;
            case ERROR_NOT_ELEVATED:
                LogMF.error(LOGGER, "Failed to delete TCP connection {0} - {1}: Running unelevated.", new Object[] { p_ioSession.getLocalAddress(), p_ioSession.getRemoteAddress() });
                break;
            default:
                LogMF.error(LOGGER, "Failed to delete TCP connection {0} - {1}: Unknown error.", new Object[] { p_ioSession.getLocalAddress(), p_ioSession.getRemoteAddress() });
                break;

        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Searches elsewhere indicate you can get 317 if the socket doesn't exist (which isn't in the docs but apparently the case) and that the error code is unreliable.  Is this a possibility?

Comment: @DanielWiddis thank you for this hint. I come across this myself (see my answer below). It's just about the docs I think,

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the return code was missleading.
The actual problem was my implementation of htons. After using the native implementation via JNA as well, the problem went away and when running elevated the functionality was given.